# nvm installing yarn either on a Node version folder or in one folder regardless of Node version?

Tags: npm, yarnpkg, nvm, serve

It is a bit strange that on my MacBook Air, npm installed yarn on

```
$ which yarn
/Users/peter/.npm-global/bin/yarn
```

but on my other iMac, it is installed on a "per Node version folder":

```
$ which yarn
/Users/peterimac/.nvm/versions/node/v16.0.0/bin/yarn
```

Which one is more correct, and should I and how do I adjust the other Mac back to the "correct" mode?  But on the iMac, it is strange that if I do

```
yarn use 16
yarn build
```

and then it says to use `yarn global add serve` and then `serve -s build` but it kept on saying `serve` does exist no matter how I `source ~/.profile` and `source ~/.zprofile`.  I have to `npm i -g serve` for it to exist.

Also, on the first Mac, the `yarn` and `serve` also do not need to be installed for any different versions of Node. The same version of `yarn` and `serve` seemed to be used no matter which version of Node I change to using `nvm use 14` or `nvm use 16`. So I am not sure if this is the correct behavior.

Is one Mac more correct than the other, and how to fix it back to the correct way and what about the `serve` not installed issue?

Answer (score 1):

I found part of the answer:  if your `yarn` is at

```
/Users/peter/.npm-global/bin/yarn
```

that means some time in the past, you have set `.npm-global` to be a one and only path... and that would conflict with `nvm`.  So remove that line from your `~/.npmrc`, and also remove the `.npm-global` text or line from your `~/.profile`, and `.zprofile`, `.bashrc`, `.zshrc`, if any.